# Perl: How do I get values of the nested hash sorted by the keys?

Tags: perl, sorting, reference

I am experimenting with a nested data structures in Perl these days. Let's say I have hash of array of hashes and I'd like to get values sorted by keys alphabetically. How do I do it?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;
#use diagnostics;
use warnings;

my $school_data = {'School' => '156', 'Pupils' => [{'Person' => {name => 'Alice', age => 10, pet => 'cat'},'id' => 56},{'Person' => {name => 'John', age => 9, pet => 'dog'},id => 4}]};

print "\$school_data:" . Dumper ($school_data);

my $ref = $school_data->{Pupils};
foreach $pupil (@$ref){
    my @temp = sort (values $pupil->{'Person'});
    print "\n@temp\n";
}
```

Gives me an output:

```
    $school_data: $VAR1 = {
              'School' => '156',
              'Pupils' => [
                            {
                              'id' => 56,
                              'Person' => {
                                            'pet' => 'cat',
                                            'name' => 'Alice',
                                            'age' => 10
                                          }
                            },
                            {
                              'Person' => {
                                            'age' => 9,
                                            'name' => 'John',
                                            'pet' => 'dog'
                                          },
                              'id' => 4
                            }
                          ]
            };



10 Alice cat

9 John dog
```

And I wish to get values sorted by keys alphabetically (pet name age):

```
cat Alice 10

dog John 9
```

Looking forward to your help. Thank you.

Comment: Sorted by all three keys? Or just a particular one?

Comment: [`$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes as I'm sure you know, don't store any sort of ordering, just key and value mappings.

But the `sort` function can take pretty much arbitrary code, that returns position dependant negative/0/positive to define sort order.

But you need to sort your 'top level' based on a subkey.

If you need to output values in a particular order - remember hashes are unordered you can use a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;

#use diagnostics;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @things = qw ( pet name age );

my $school_data = {
   'School' => '156',
   'Pupils' => [
      {  'Person' => { name => 'Alice', age => 10, pet => 'cat' },
         'id'     => 56
      },
      { 'Person' => { name => 'John', age => 9, pet => 'dog' }, id => 4 }
   ]
};

print "\$school_data:" . Dumper( $school_data->{Pupils} );

foreach my $pupil ( sort { $_ -> {Person} -> {name} 
                       cmp $_ -> {Person} -> {name} } 
                               @{ $school_data->{Pupils} } )
{
   print join " ", @{$pupil->{Person}}{@things}, "\n";
}
```

For multi-key sort, sort works just fine - provided the thing it returns is a numeric value.

So you could:

```
sort { $_ -> {Person} -> {name} cmp $_ -> {Person} -> {name}
    || $_ -> {Person} -> {age} <=> $_ -> {Person} -> {age}
    || $_ -> {Person} -> {pet} <=> $_ -> {Person} -> {pet} }
```

Comment: Did not know I can use slice with a hash. Many thanks!